# Issue with a simple android program

Tags: android

Code:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    Thread timer = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }

    };
    timer.start();
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    this.finish();

}
  }
```

As you guys can see, this a very simple program which will show a splash screen and then will open the url in the browser. Everything is fine up to here. Now by using the back button I exit from the app. But as soon as I try to press the installed app icon, the system gives me a toast saying `"app is not installed on your phone"`.

When I check the running services, its always there and my `logcat` says: `"Launcher does not have permission to launch the intent"`.

So my 1st question: Why my app is running all the time, although I have called the `finish()` in the `onPause()` method?

Q2. What this `logcat` message indicates?

Here is my manifest (guess you're thinking that I haven't added the `uses-permission` for internet but I had):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.abc.xyz.main"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.1" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"  android:description="@string/appdescription">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>


   </application>

   </manifest>
```

Here is the `logcat`:

```
04-29 23:17:56.745: I/ActivityManager(68): Starting activity: Intent {act=android.intent.action.MAIN   cat[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000        cmp=com.vayyoo.epost.main/.SplashActivity }
04-29 23:17:56.745: W/ActivityManager(68): Permission Denial: starting Intent {      act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.vayyoo.epost.main/.SplashActivity } from ProcessRecord{45cfc0f8 240:com.android.launcher/10025} (pid=240, uid=10025) requires android.permission.INTERNET
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240): Launcher does not have the permission to launch Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.vayyoo.epost.main/.SplashActivity }. Make sure to create a MAIN intent-filter for the corresponding activity or use the exported attribute for this activity. tag=ApplicationInfo(title=ePost) intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.vayyoo.epost.main/.SplashActivity }
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.vayyoo.epost.main/.SplashActivity } from ProcessRecord{45cfc0f8 240:com.android.launcher/10025} (pid=240, uid=10025) requires android.permission.INTERNET
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1298)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1373)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.startActivityForResult(Launcher.java:1053)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.startActivitySafely(Launcher.java:1462)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at com.android.launcher2.AllApps2D.onItemClick(AllApps2D.java:178)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-29 23:17:56.785: E/Launcher(240):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 23:17:59.855: W/KeyCharacterMap(240): No keyboard for id 0
04-29 23:17:59.855: W/KeyCharacterMap(240): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest also...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using  Ice Cream Sandwich,(I remember reading this somewhere in SO) not only does the permission have to be in its own tag  the application cannot have the attribute "android.permission.INTERNET" at the same time.. so just remove this from application node and try...

Comment: dear raju base paltform is froyo 2.2.

Comment: Ok.. but why are you using android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" in application.. when you have already declared the permission earlier..?

Comment: Thanks mr.raju (typo, my mistake)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the:

```
android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

From this part:

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"  android:description="@string/appdescription">
```

But leave it in the other part of your manifest.